# In ActiveRecord, how to check if an object property is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I need to check if a certain property is not set.

I imagine something like this but It doesn't work.

```
@users = User.find_all_by_role(["role = ?",nil])
```

I tried some other variants with no luck.

I guess this should be pretty straightforward.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ActiveRecord's pre-3.0 syntax:

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => { :role => nil })
```

After 3.0 you can write:

```
@users = User.where(:role => nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `@users = User.find(:all, :conditions=>'role is null')`

Comment: Thank you, there's a cleaner way above.

Answer (score 0):

```
@users = User.where(:roles => nil).all
```

There's no need to break into SQL for this.